# Adding Padding to absolutely positioned div within parent expanding outside parent

Tags: css

On the following site, I have a child div absolutely positioned at the bottom of its parent div - the hero image.

http://helpthemgrow.staging.wpengine.com/

Adding padding to the child div causes it to break out of parent div

Here is my code:

```
<div class="home-hero">
    <div class="home-hero-img">
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="home-image widget-area">
                <section id="media_image-2" class="widget widget_media_image">
                <div class="widget-wrap">
                    <img width="200" height="300" src="http://helpthemgrow.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/help-tehm-grow-book-cover-200x300.jpg" class="image wp-image-43  attachment-medium size-medium" alt="" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;" srcset="http://helpthemgrow.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/help-tehm-grow-book-cover-200x300.jpg 200w, http://helpthemgrow.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/help-tehm-grow-book-cover.jpg 250w" sizes="(max-width: 200px) 100vw, 200px">
                </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end wrap -->
    </div><!-- end home-hero-img -->
    <div class="home-hero-cta">
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="three-fourths first">
                <div class="home-hero-cta-text">Careers are developed one conversation at a time – over time.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="one-fourth">
                <a class="button" href="/book/">Learn more</a>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end wrap -->
    </div><!-- end home-hero-cta -->
</div><!-- end home-hero -->
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.home-hero {
    background-image: url('/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/htg-hero-slide-one.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 100px 0 150px 0;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    position:relative;
}
.home-hero-cta {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

.home-hero-cta .wrap {
    padding: 20px 0;
}   

.home-hero-cta-text {
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `home-hero-cta` class has a set height...

Comment: Well f me...that fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the set height that you have for `home-hero-cta` and that should fix your issue.